# Batch/javascript file to remove comma at the end of the lines from multiple files

Tags: javascript, batch-file

As I said, I want to create a batch or javascript file to remove comma at the end of every line (if there is one) from multiple files at once.
So far I've done some research and found this:

---

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    type FILE1.ISO | cscript //nologo //e:javascript "%~f0" > NEWFILE1.ISO
    type FILE2.ISO | cscript //nologo //e:javascript "%~f0" > NEWFILE2.ISO

    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************
    while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace(/,$/,''));
```

---

PROBLEM: The file names are different everytime I use the script so is there a chance I don't have to put the name of each file everytime I use it? is there a way I could just say find .iso files in C:/foldername and remove comma's from it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Then pass arguments via cmd line and use `%1` for the first arg etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch option. Simply test if the last character is a comma, if not print the line as is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type *.iso') do (
  set "lines=%%i"
  set "test=!lines:~-1!"
  if "!lines:~-1!"=="," (call set "lines=%%lines:!test!=%%")
  echo !lines!
)
```